# Configure apache solr in my system

Tags: java, solr

Error.

[image]

Please give me solution

Comment: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrConfigXml

Answer (score 0):

Kindly follow the instruction in the URL specified:

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrTomcat (It has solr release wise configuration)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Tomcat is deprecated from 5.0, as Solr moves to unbundled itself from the application container.

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that your Solr server was started with an invalid parameter for the installation directory (as Dsolr.install.dir is in the path). You probably wanted to set this property when starting the container (with the -D argument) or you've added a property in your solr configuration file in the wrong format.